# text match and replacement in R

Tags: r, regex, replace

I am working on a project, where a part of cleaning data is stripping out the country names. My original data frame (named noaa) LOCATION_NAME column would look like this:

> head(noaa$LOCATION_NAME,5)
>   [1] "JORDAN:  BAB-A-DARAA,AL-KARAK"
>   [2] "SYRIA:  UGARIT"
>   [3] "TURKMENISTAN:  W"
>   [4] "GREECE:  THERA ISLAND (SANTORINI)"
>   [5] "ISRAEL:  ARIHA (JERICHO)"

To strip out the country names I'm using:

> noaa$LOCATION_NAME <- gsub('^.*: +', '', noaa$LOCATION_NAME)

It works pretty well, however, I still get entries like: 
"ANTAKYA (ANTIOCH); SYRIA" 
or 
"DIMASHQ; TURKEY:ANTIOCH; LEBANON:TARABULUS" (because the expression doesn't begin with "countryname:"

Removing anything ending with a ":" is not an option, in case of:
"CHINA:  YUNNAN PROVINCE:  MIDU"

I would like to retain "YUNNAN PROVINCE:  MIDU"

for "PAKISTAN:  INDUS DELTA; INDIA: SAMAWANI (SAMAJI)"

I would like to retain "INDUS DELTA; SAMAWANI (SAMAJI)"

I also have instances like "SWITZERLAND" (no ":"), where I guess I would put just " " (space).

I have in my data frame a column with country names and I could make a vector with unique country names. I was wondering if there is a smart method to check if a part of a string matches a country name in my country column and if yes, then I could remove it.

I would be grateful for some help on this.

Comment: Just sort the country names by reverse alphabetic. Then join all the strings into an alternation, something like  `'(?:'` + join('|', array) + `')'` Then you have to add boundary constructs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes a regex or list of patterns (separated  by |). 
   noaa <- read.table(text='
    LOCATION_NAME
    "JORDAN: BAB-A-DARAA,AL-KARAK"
    "SYRIA: UGARIT"
    "TURKMENISTAN: W"
    "GREECE: THERA ISLAND (SANTORINI)"
    "ISRAEL: ARIHA (JERICHO)"
    "SWITZERLAND SOMEWHERE"
    ', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

```
countries <- c("JORDAN", "SYRIA", "GREECE", "SWITZERLAND")

# build an or list of patterns including country name ending with
# either (in priority order) <space>: or : or <space>
patterns <- paste0(countries, collapse="(\\s\\:|\\:|\\s)|")
trimws(gsub(patterns, "", noaa$LOCATION_NAME))

# [1] "BAB-A-DARAA,AL-KARAK"     "UGARIT"                   "TURKMENISTAN: W"          "THERA ISLAND (SANTORINI)"
# [5] "ISRAEL: ARIHA (JERICHO)"  "SOMEWHERE"
```

Comment: This works really well, thank you! I modified the regex to include ";" and it's doing what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Since the country string might be in different section of the string, you can partition it using ";" and ":" first then do a match against your unique country names:

```
#dfOfCountries is the data.frame containing all the countries as mentioned in your qn
distinctcountries <- unique(dfOfCountries$COUNTRY)

noaa$COUNTRY <- sapply(noaa$LOCATION_NAME, function(x) {
    strparts <- trimws(unlist(lapply(strsplit(x, ":")[[1]], strsplit, split=";")))
    strparts[strparts %in% distinctcountries]
})
```